# how to take many multiple inputs in java and then perform a same operation on all those inputs

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class sexy
{
  void even(String s)
  {
    for( int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
    {
      if((i==0) ||(i%2==0))
      {
       System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
      }
    }
  }
  void odd(String s)
  {
    for( int i=0;i<s.length() ; i++)
    {
      if(i%2!=0)
      {
        System.out.print(s.charAt(i));
      }
    }
  }


}

class sassy
{
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    sexy se = new sexy();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i=0,p;
    p=scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();
    String s;
    while(i<p)
    {
     s = scan.nextLine();
     se.even(s);
     System.out.print(" ");
     se.odd(s);
     i++;
    }
    scan.close();
   }
}
```

Now here i am able to take multiple inputs..and after every input i have to perform the operation on that particular input.. But I want to take multiple inputs at first and then perform the same operation on all the inputs using minimum variables..(if possible just one)

Comment: Looks like you lack of experience with programming. Did you go though the [basics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like you would either need a string array or a string arraylist.

You would use a string array if you knew how many inputs you would get, and an arraylist if you don't know how many inputs would be put in.

The code would look something like this:

```
ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
```

To put the values in, you would use `lines.put()`, and then `lines.get(i)` in your for loop to get values back out.

So to use it in your program, just add all the lines that the user inputs into the arraylist, and then traverse the arraylist to do the even and odd functions.

Good luck!